# Using Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar with Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar crashes the app on android L(api v21)

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

Here is how my resources look like

```
res/values/styles.xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>
```

like it says [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/get-started.html)

```
res/values-v21/styles.xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
```

and the AndroidManifest.xml has

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

in my MainActivity.java i inherit from the ActionBarActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
....
...
}
```

Now when i run the app on KitKat (API 19) the app runs and i see Dark Action bar and the material design but when i run it on Android L (API 21), the app crashes saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`. I know this happens because i inherit from `ActionBarActivity` but if i use an `appcompat` theme in `values-v21/styles.xml` then how would i use the material theme?

Comment: i get Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar' in res/values-v21/styles.xml, and in <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar"> </style> plz help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Theme.AppCompat` inherits from Material through Platform theme if is running on Lollipop device: `res/values-v21/styles.xml` is not necessary in this case.

Comment: i get Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar' in  res/values-v21/styles.xml, and in <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
    </style>  plz help